# Django test wont accept test user

Tags: python, django, django-testing

I'm currently trying to create Django tests for a mock website that I've created.
Here is my test:

```
class ListingsTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_listing(self):
        user = User.objects.create_user(username='test')
        user.set_password('test')
        user.save()

        c = Client()
        c.login(username='test', password='test')
        category = Category.objects.get_or_create(name='test')

        t_listing = {
                    'title': 'Test',
                    'email': 'test@test.com',
                    'phone_number': '4057081902',
                    'description': 'Test',
                    'category': category,
                    'user': user,
                    }

        form = ListingForm(data=t_listing)
        self.assertEqual(form.errors, {})
        self.assertEqual(form.is_valid(),True)
```

My model:

```
class Listing(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=12, default='')
    listing_price = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to='listing_images')
    description = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Here is my ListingForm:

```
class ListingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    image = forms.FileField(required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Listing
        fields = [
            'user',
            'title',
            'email',
            'phone_number',
           'description',
            'listing_price',
            'image',
            'category',
        ]
        widgets = {'user': forms.HiddenInput()}
```

And here is the error that I am getting:

```
FAIL: test_listing (seller.tests.ListingsTestCase)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/local/CE/mwilcoxen/project/hermes/seller/tests.py", line 35, in test_listing
self.assertEqual(form.errors, {})
AssertionError: {'category': [u'Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.'], 'user': [u'Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.']} != {}
```

So I used my first assertEquals to be able to see what is throwing errors, and I used some breakpoints to know that my test user is able to login, but for some reason its just not working.  If anyone could give me some help that would be great.

Comment: What's your `ListingForm` code please?

Comment: Can you paste the ListingForm ?

Comment: If you want to set the user field to the logged in user, you shouldn't include it as a hidden field, because it doesn't prevent visitors from changing the value. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9332040/in-django-how-do-you-pass-a-foreignkey-into-an-instance-of-a-model/9332588#9332588) for a different approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the ids of the `user` and `category`, instead of the actual objects.

```
t_listing = {
    'title': 'Test',
    'email': 'test@test.com',
    'phone_number': '4057081902',
    'description': 'Test',
    'category': category.id,
    'user': user.id,
```

}

Note that [`get_or_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) returns a tuple, so you should change that line to:

```
category, created = Category.objects.get_or_create(name='test')
```

Comment: It shows `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'id'`

Comment: Duh, i should've realized that when it told me that.  i appreciate it so much, this was making me want to pull my hair out