# How to save forms field in django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

i have some fields in my django models.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(User)
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    product_cost = models.IntegerField(default=0,null=True, blank=True)
    product_description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0,null=True, blank=True)
    product_image = models.FileField(upload_to='images/',blank=True,null=True,)
    coupon_code = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_name or u''
```

when i use form to save all the data from front end in my database i can do this.

```
class DocumentForm(forms.ModelForm):


    class Meta:
        model = Product

        fields = ('user','product_name','product_image','product_cost','product_description','product_description','coupon_code')
```

Problem is this i don't want to allow user to fill user data from front-end.when user save data it save request.user to user.
I am new to work with forms  so facing some issues.
Please help me how can i do this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can do that by removing those fields

Comment: I f i remove user field then how can i provide value to that field.that is mandatory field

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9332040/in-django-how-do-you-pass-a-foreignkey-into-an-instance-of-a-model/9332588#9332588).

Answer (score 0):

In `fields` you have to remove `user`:
so it will look like this:
class DocumentForm(forms.ModelForm):

```
class Meta:
    model = Product

    fields = ('product_name','product_image','product_cost','product_description','product_description','coupon_code')
```

and in your views.py when you save the data from the form you have write something like this:

```
user = request.user
```

in this case user will be saved if he is authenticated.

If you want that not authenticated user could fill the form too, you have to change in your model.py `Product` class from:

```
user=models.ForeignKey(User)
```

to:

```
user=models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
```

then not authenticated user will be `NULL`.

Comment: error showing.NOT NULL constraint failed: userInfo_product.user_id